# Работа с базами данный SQL

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

на работе появилась необходимость для работы с SQL.
Мне установили SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager и сказали, что доустановят если ещё что-то нужно. Мне нужно создавать базу в дальнейшем работать с ней так же использовать её с c# и создавать запросы, не очень понимаю какое ПО для этого нужно, но по моему нужно ещё как минимум SQL server management studio. Скажите пожалуйста, что необходимо иметь установленным, желательно чтоб а дальнейшем я могла работать без подключения к интернету

Comment: В наше время работать без подключения к интернету не комильфо. Постоянно нужно устанавливать какие-нибудь nuget-пакеты, постоянно пушить изменения кода в git, постоянно искать недостающую информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Собственно нужен сам SQL Server. Можно начать с бесплатной Express Edition.
2. Да, SQL Server Management Studio.
3. Visual Studio для разработки на c#, бесплатная Community Edition.
4. Книги по SQL Server, c# и .NET.

Всё это будет работать без подключения к Интернету (кроме справки). Установочные пакеты скачать на сайте Microsoft.